# Fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64" conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

Tags: python, sql-server

I want to set SQL Server as the data source of python codes. I have Windows 7, ananconda, python 3.6. I am using the following command;

"pip install pyodbc==3.1.1"

Now I received an error "fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'".

I think this error is caused by including odbc32.lib. There are two odbc32.lib in my computer. They are in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86

I tried adding both paths to the LIB and LIBPATH environment variables or adding only one of them into these two variables. But I still have this error.

Your help is appreciated!

[image]